# Error there is no argument given for sender when call event handler for CheckBox

Tags: c#

I want to calculate the amout of some Entry's with this, the total of 2 Entry's . That works  with a ButtonClick event.

```
private void Rekenklik(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var t1 = Decimal.Parse(Ebb1.Text);
        var t2 = Decimal.Parse(Ebb2.Text);

        var total = t1 + t2;
        string totleString1 = total.ToString();
        int length1 = totleString1.Length;
        Totaal.Text = length1 > 3 ? totleString1.Insert(length1 - 3, ",") : totleString1;

    }
```

I also use want put this in with a CheckBoxChanged event.

```
 <CheckBox
                        x:Name="Cbbb1"
                        Grid.Row="0"
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        CheckedChanged="Cbbb1_CheckedChanged" />
```

In `Maui` it is giving a Error on `Rekenklik();` when i use it in `CheckChanged` event.

```
private void Cbbb1_CheckedChanged(object sender, CheckedChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            {

                if (e.Value)
                {
                    Ebb1.Text = "754831";
                }
                else
                {
                    Ebb1.Text = "0";
                
                }
                Rekenklik();   ///////// Error on this

            }
             
        }
```

> Error CS7036  There is no argument given that corresponds to the
> required formal parameter 'sender' of 'MainPage.Rekenklik(object,
> EventArgs)'   Testing (net6.0-android), Testing (net6.0-ios), Testing
> (net6.0-maccatalyst), Testing
> (net6.0-windows10.0.19041)    G:\source\Testing\Testing\MainPage.xaml.cs  33  Active

When i use Rekenklik(); with a ButtonClick it works , but i want to used to with a CheckBox.
Is `Maui` not ready for this or am i doing something wrong ?

Using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - Preview
Version 17.1.0 Preview 1.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it , i forgot to remove this `object sender, EventArgs e`

```
public void Rekenklik()
{
    var t1 = Decimal.Parse(Ebb1.Text);
    var t2 = Decimal.Parse(Ebb2.Text);

    var total = t1 + t2;
    string totleString1 = total.ToString();
    int length1 = totleString1.Length;
    Totaal.Text = length1 > 3 ? totleString1.Insert(length1 - 3, ",") : totleString1;

}
```